# How to check if vertex exists (on polyline) based on location of point layer using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, intersection, topology

Using ArcGIS for Desktop Advanced 10.1 (with all extensions)

I am building a centerline network that will be used by a MapObjects program to do routing based on "turns at any vertex" (as opposed to turns only at endpoints...)  What I am trying to do is identify overpasses/underpasses that have a shared vertex with the road that crosses it (but is not considered an intersection)  If there is a shared vertex, then the mapping program will (incorrectly) make a turn where there is not one physically possible.  What I've done so far is build a topology using the "Must not intersect (Line)" rule.  I export the errors to a feature class, and now I have a bunch of points at intersections that I need to check.  What I'm wondering is if there is a way to cycle through each point and check to see if a vertex exists where the centerline intersects the point.  Here's what I've come up with so far...

```
import arcpy

fcPoints = "C:/MyPointLayer..."
fcCenterlines = "C:/MyCenterlineLayer..."

rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fcPoints)
for row in rows:
    # For each point, select the centerlines that touch (intersect) that point
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(fcPoints, "NEW_SELECTION", "\"OBJECTID\" = " + str(row.getValue("OBJECTID")))
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(fcCenterlines, "INTERSECT", fcPoints)
    # Need code here to cycle through each selected centerline and determine if a vertex exists at the point's SHAPE@XY location?
    #PSEUDO CODE:
    for each line in selection:
        vertexExists = False
        for each vertex in line:
            if vertex.xy == point.xy:
                vertexExists = True

        # If there is a matching vertice, then update a field in the point fc to "FLAG" it...
        if vertexExists == True:
            row.setValue("FLAG", "CHECK THIS INTERSECTION")
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Or.... is there an easier way...?  I would be looking at about 2000 points to check...

Comment: Uh, yeah, that's a pretty good idea... wasn't aware of that tool... that works perfectly... thanks!

Comment: @Hornbydd I think you should turn your Comment into an Answer because it looks like it answered the Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way of achieving this is to "explode" you polyline into its individual vertices using the [feature to vertices](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003p000000) tool. You can then run the [Generate near table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Generate_Near_Table/00080000001n000000/) tool with this layer on your intersection points layer. A distance of zero would indicate they are the same location.

Both these tools require you to have an Advance license level.

Answer (score 1):

Hornbydd has a valid answer of course if you have the advanced license.  Here is the work around if you do not:

- Use the [Make Feature Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Make_Feature_Layer/00170000006p000000/) method on your polyline layer before your selection methods, to store the selected features.
- Finally, to pull out the selected polyline vertices (from the feature layer) and get their x/y coordinates to compare against your point layer (coordinate field values) you can reference this script snippet from this [forum post](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/49581-get-vertex-coordinates):

> ```
> updateRows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(lineFC) # for your situation a search cursor will do
> for updateRow in updateRows: # looping through lines
>    vertexList = []
>    shapeObj = updateRow.getValue(shapeFieldName)
>    partObj = shapeObj.getPart(0)
>    for pointObj in partObj: 
>       vertexList.append((pointObj.X, pointObj.Y))
>       # continue with your update cursor on your point layer
> ```